# Proportionally increasing the width of a curved line

Tags: modeling

Good day!

I'm trying to increase the width of the line as it goes, so i want the width to increase propotionally like this:

[image]

I tried to rotate it, use proportional editing, but it didn't work well. Also, however, I could do this manually with edge slide and alt, but I'm afraid it would be not so smooth.

Is there's another way to proportionally move the outer line of verticies?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello :). Easy. Hide the other vertices. Set pivot point to 3D cursor and scale the last vertex with *Proportional editing > Connected*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but one that springs to mind is to construct your curve with a *Curve* modifier deformation, either of a long, thin plane subdivided along its length, or an array of smaller face-planes, merged in the *Array* modifier.

[image]

Then the curve's 'Radius' becomes available for adjustment. With Proprtional Editing, set to 'Connected Only', you can select one end or the other of the curve, with an appropriate falloff profile and size,  <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> scale the radius of the curve progressively from one end to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to make a spiral,

1. Go to edit -> Prefrences -> Add-ons
2. Search extra objects
3. Enable curve: extra objects
4. Press Shift + A -> Curve -> Curve Spirals -> Archemedian(U can experiment with others too)
5. Set Turns, Steps, Radius, Radius Growth and Height.
6. Press F3 -> Search convert to mesh -> Click it
7. Go to modifiers and add a skin modifier.
8. Go to edit mode and select all the vertices.
9. Go to object mode. Press Ctrl+ A and set an appropriate thickness.
10. If you want your spiral to be 2 - dimensional, you can just apply the skin modifier and scale all the vertices on Z Axis to 0(Don't forget to merge by distance)

Result:

[image]